# how handle Crosscutting concerns in jersy jaxrs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

My problem is when we use Spring boot like framework, we can easily handle AOP. but how we handle AOP with jersy jaxrs project

Comment: AOP isn't Spring's exclusive property. There are plenty of AOP libraries to go around.

Comment: @Kayaman what are the library we can use with jersey

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot is just a bootstrapping framework. For REST we can use Spring Boot to bootstrap Spring MVC *or* Jersey fully integrated with Spring. If you choose the latter route, then you can use the Spring AOP with Jersey. All you need to do is make your Jersey resources Spring `@Component`s to able to intercept them. See an official example of [Spring Boot and Jersey](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey).

If you don't want to use Spring Boot to bootstrap your Jersey app, then you can still integrate Spring with Jersey. Remember the AOP is not tied to Spring Boot, it is tied to the Spring Framework, which are different things. You can see an example of Jersey with Spring (without Spring Boot) [here](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-spring-example).

If you don't want to involve Spring at all, then Jersey has a DI framework, [HK2](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/), which has [it's own AOP](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/extensibility.html#interception). You can see a full example [here](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-validate-return)